# Withdraw from Bity contract to wallet

Tags: mist

I've bought some ETH on bity.com which they delivered in a contract with the address 0x834145878D5e82D21CFaa27BC71ddD60194E8198.

I now want to transfer the ETH of this contract to my personal wallet, but I can't seem to find out how to manage this. I've downloaded the Ethereum Wallet and managed to connect to my contract, so it shows up in contracts tab and I've transferred 2 ETH into my personal wallet for enough gas.

Can anybody help me to get my ETH out of that contract please?

Comment: They provide you with a contract and don't tell you how to use it?

Comment: 0x834145878D5e82D21CFaa27BC71ddD60194E8198 is no contract at all. Did they provide you with keys? If yes, put it in the keystore directory on your disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, there you go. I've got the JSON data but I didn't realize that I have to make a file out of it and put it in the keystore directory!

Thank you very much, that solved my problem!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted by clicking the green tick on the left.